# Using an old version of log4net: how do I use RollingFileAppender?

Tags: log4net, log4net-configuration

I am using an old version of log4net: 1.2.0.21221.

When I used the new version of log4net, I was able to successfully make use of rolling file appender.

Using the properties:

```
log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["LogName"] = string.Concat(fileName, "_", dateTimeInfo, ".log");

log4net.ThreadContext.Properties["Version"] = "1";

XmlConfigurator.Configure();
```

These things are not available in the older version of log4net. How do I make use of my rolling file appender defined in my config file? I need a brand new name for config file everytime I start my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason for you to be using the GlobalContext for naming your file properly.

See the following example:

```xml
<appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value="FILENAME" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Date" />
  <staticLogFileName value="false" />
  <maximumFileSize value="100KB" />
  <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
  <datePattern value="-yyyyMMddhhmmss'.log'" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
```

The `<file value="..." />` is the first part of your filename.  The PRE filename if you will.  Look a little farther down and there is the `<datePattern value="..." />` which is the rest of the filename.  It gets APPENDED to the value you put in the file attribute.  In my example it will output a file named `FILENAME-20110124090021.log`.

If you notice the last part of my datePattern it contains single quotes '.log' inside double quotes and that simply escapes any values from being evaluated by the datetime call.

Comment: But pls tell me where is the path of this log file... where o i get to set the path of my log file..

Comment: can u pls provide me with a sample code to do it.. not able to achieve the same.. thanks

Comment: the log file will be output to the same location as your executable.  If you want it to be output to a place such as C:\LOGS then just update file value="C:\Logs\FILENAME"

Comment: pls tell me is there anything in the code which i need to set.. I am using only DOMConfigurator.Configure() to configure the logger. But the log file is not appearing in the executing assembly folder. So pls help me